# Coda 2 PHP errors in preview

Tags: php, coda

How can I make Coda 2 show me errors in the php scripts that I am working on in preview mode. I have MAMP running locally. When everything is fine I can preview the file normally. When there is an error I have no way of locating it.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` Please also try to google and look at the documentation before posting

Comment: Oliver Queen, I supposed what I should have said is I am looking for the Coda specific solution. Nothing shows in the preview window if there is an error.